# How to overlay polygon shapefiles with different attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I have 2 shapefiles of the entire state of PA. One shapefile has median income for each county. The other has number of flu cases for each county. I would like to know, how should I combine them? My ultimate goal is to clip select counties from a combined shapefile.

Comment: Do you want to join the attribute table of both to a single shapefile?

Comment: Questions like this can often be improved by explaining "why", not just "what". Could you edit your question to explain what you are trying to achieve with this analysis? Sometimes that can help to produce a much more useful set of answers to your question. Also, letting us know what you've already tried, what did and didn't work, and what you'd hoped for instead can help us to help you. Just click "edit" below your question to update the question.

Comment: Make sure you also normalize for population. Otherwise you will propabably end up with a population density map.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to try the **[Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000)** tool and look at the result to see that the output contains attributes from both input shapefiles.

You can then use the same result with the **[Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Select/000800000005000000/)** tool on a county name to perform the desired "clip".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a join on countyname or countyfips or whatever common non-spatial attribute they share.  I would only bother with a spatial join (from polygon label point to polygon) if there was no common attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 'spatial join'. Or perhaps a 'join' by some common attribute, perhaps "zip code" per county, or county name.

Comment: A spatial Join should be a last resort.It's computational intensive, and can give erroneous results.